# How to enable Ctrl + Shift + V in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) / command prompt (cmd)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Windows 10 Pro (Version 1803, OS build 17134.619)? Reading [how-to guides online](https://www.howtogeek.com/353200/how-to-enable-copy-and-paste-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10s-bash-shell/) it states to:

1. Open a command line window
2. Right-click an empty part of the title bar and select "Properties"
3. Select the "Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> as Copy/Paste" option, and then click the "OK" button.

The "Properties" menu in the article looks like this and has the "Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> as Copy/Paste" option:

[image]

This option is however missing on my computer:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How to enable Ctrl + Shift + V in Windows 10 Pro (Version 1803, OS build 17134.619)?

You are running the incorrect version of Windows 10.  The feature in question is only a feature of the `October 2018 Update (1809)`.  You currently have the `April 2018 Update (1803)` installed.

You will have to upgrade to 1809 in order to enable the option in question

[image]

> These shortcuts are available in the **October 2018 Update**, which was originally codenamed Redstone 5.

Source: [How to Enable Copy and Paste Keyboard Shortcuts in Windows 10’s Bash Shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/353200/how-to-enable-copy-and-paste-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10s-bash-shell/)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem from another angle, you can configure ssh server in your WSL, and then use PowerShell to connect to it. After that, copy and paste won't be a problem.

Comment: Ugh. Does this enable ^C and ^V to be used properly? Or are they still obscured by Windows copy and paste? And does Powershell support all the CMD features?